# Histogram 3D: use different bin width in two directions

Tags: graphics, graphics3d, histograms

I'm trying to plot an histogram of a set of data, I would like to use a bin of different width in x and y direction.

I've tried using the following two codes:

```
Histogram3D[data, {0.2, 0.098}, "PDF"]
```

and

```
Histogram3D[data, {{0.2, 0.098}}, "PDF"]
```

However the code is not working.

I know it's a basic question, but does anybody have any suggestion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tak a closer look at documentation:

```
data = RandomReal[1, {100, 2}];


Histogram3D[data, {{.2}, {.5}}]
```

[image]

> The following bin specifications *bpsec* can be given:
>
> {w}   use bins of width w
>
> (...)
>
> {xspec,yspec} give different x and y specifications

ergo:

```
{{wx}, {wy}}
```

Comment: The specification should give an example of the usage. This post explains how to use it far quicker than decoding the documentation. All the documentation needs is a single example. Using the braces twice for example is confusing.